# AntRun task sequence?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am new to Maven and Ant concepts but have beginner's idea.

So in POM.xml
I used "antrun" plugin and set goals like.

1. Remove a jar say myext.jar
2. Now create myext.jar
3. copy myext.jar to some other location.

I want to know, Will tasks run in the given sequence or just in random order?

Comment: AFAIK order of tasks runned by Maven is as the order of the Maven goals binded to the default lifecycle. I would recommend to achieve what you want, via say a bash script. You can run that separately, or maybe use maven-exec or bash-maven-plugin. Also if maven/ant is not mandatory, check out Buildr!

Comment: What happens when you run it?  Also, you could share relevant pom snippet for someone to respond suitably.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven - determine order of different plugin goals in the same phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391996/maven-determine-order-of-different-plugin-goals-in-the-same-phase)